# threading route params with react-router and redux container components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

Hopefully this is a simple question that I'm just having trouble phrasing.
Prior to using react-router:

My app is structured in a way that there is a list of items, clicking an item sets a `selected` state item in my redux store.

When an item is selected, app renders a container component. This component is quite complex and has several other child container components where I use a selector to `getSelectedItem(state)`.

Now that is fine, but when switching to `react-router`, now the only component with knowledge of the `selected` value is the most parent component which gets the `this.props.params.selected` value. Because `selected` is no longer being stored in the state, it is managed by the router, is it necessary for me to thread the `selected` value through to all the children container components as well? Where i would now use a selector like `getItem(state, selected)` or something to that effect.

Hopefully that's clear, perhaps i should have been threading that value through all along? Not sure on best practice there. Thanks.

Comment: Provide, please, some code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass location/pathname/params explicitly as props to child components.

`react-router` currently provides `context.router` which will help you navigate forward and backward but it doesn't give you the details of the current route. In earlier versions, there used to be `context.location` and `context.router.getCurrentRoutes` but they were both deprecated in v2.0.0-rc4.

> #### Changed context exports
>
> Only an object named `router` is added to context. Accessing `context.history`, `context.location`, and
>   `context.route` are all deprecated.
>
> #### Accessing location
>
> Access `location` from `this.props.location` of your route component.
>   If  you'd like to get it deeper in the tree, you can use whatever 
>   conventions your app has for getting props from high down low. One 
>   option is to put it context yourself

For further details, refer the react-router [changes](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md) done during [v2.0.0-rc4](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/compare/v1.0.3...v2.0.0-rc4).

Comment: Thanks! That clears it up I guess. I feel like this is counter-intuitive to the pattern that redux establishes with container components though.